# MySQL results from keywords

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search, keyword

I'm trying to build a simple search function in MySQL where a user can filter images by entering one or more predefined keywords. But I'm unable to get the correct output whenever I add more than one keyword.

Here's a simplified version of the database structure:

```
Table: images
- id (PK)
- title
- link

Table: keywords
- id (PK)
- keyword

Table: image_keywords
- image_id (FK)
- keyword_id (FK)
```

Data example:

```
images:
1.     Image 1 title    http://test1.com
2.     Image 2 title    http://test2.com
3.     Image 3 title    http://test3.com

keywords:
1.     Photography
2.     Landscape
3.     Skyline

image_keywords:
1.     1.
1.     2.
2.     1.
2.     3.
```

So what I'd like is to be able to search *image_keywords* for all images having **both** *Photography* and *Landscape* as a keyword and list them. But in therory an image can have an unlimited amount of keywords assisiated with it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you want:

```
select i.id, i.title
from images i
inner join image_keywords ik on i.id = ik.image_id
inner join keywords k on ik.keyword_id = k.id
where k.keyword in ('Photography', 'Landscape')
group by i.id, i.title
having count(distinct k.id) = 2
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c795/1)

Comment: Awesome, precisely what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

use a group by group by image, and then use `HAVING count = 2` or how ever many tags you searched for.

Look at the Toxi Schema here

http://tagging.pui.ch/post/37027745720/tags-database-schemas